# meta http-equiv outside of head?

Tags: html, opera, head, meta

I've been always accustomed to see meta tags inside of head. The new Opera 12.12 takes this meta out of head while saving a page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="pl-PL">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<head>
```

is this an affordable thing or a bug in Opera?

**Update for Jukka K. Korpela**

The page has following URL: http://www.espeo.pl/2012/02/26/authentication-in-angularjs-application and I save it as "HTML file with images".

Comment: It would be a bug if it occurred. But saving a file on Opera 12.12 does not create this problem in my system (Win 7). Please provide a sample URL and specify exactly how you save the page (which format).

Comment: Right, the bug is reproducible (even in Opera 12.13) as occurring when using Save As “HTML file with images”, not when saving as HTML only or in MHT format. So yes, it’s a bug and should be reported.

Comment: I stopped reporting bugs to them. They never pay attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This link should help you find the answer:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4.1

also according to w3schools(which cant be taken as a genuine spec): "*Note: `<meta>` tags always goes inside the `<head>` element.*"

Answer (score 1):

It isn't valid HTML. Meta elements may only be children of the head element.

It is probably a bug, but might be a deliberate violation of the HTML spec on Opera's part to ensure that the character encoding information is parsed before any attributes on the `<head>` element (in case they contain characters that aren't in the default encoding).

Comment: It’s hardly deliberate, because it only occurs when saving HTML with images and since it saves no imaginable purpose to put the `meta` tag before the `head` tag. There are reasons to put it right after it, on the grounds you mention.